# Make Autotransition in Jira

Tags: jira, transition

**PROBLEM**: There are two Jira projects: A & B. When project A transitions, project B should as well. Issues from projects A & B are linked.

**RESEARCH**: There is an [ILA plugin for Jira](https://ilaesolution.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/IU/pages/19431440/Jira+ILA+Utilities+REST+APIs) and in its Update Status Transition you can select issues with JQL and set their statuses.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/CnmLHi5.png]

I've conducted a JQL, but it is related to current issue, and I need it is a variable which is unavailable (find issues of project A, linked to issue B-3 from project B):

```
project = "A" AND issue IN LinkedIssuesByJQL("issue = B-3")
```

**QUESTION**: How to refer to a variable like `$currentIssue`? Any other free plugins? Maybe using Jira API?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the ILA plugin for Jira but it seems that it does not provide the functionality you require. You might want to reach out to them and ask if they can implement this feature for you. But based on their [documentation](https://ilaesolution.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/IU/pages/30179394/ILA+Utilities+For+Jira), it's a rather simple plugin for smaller use cases.

However, your use case also sounds you might want to use some more automation than this. Here are three alternatives you might want to consider for your problem:

**Jira Service Desk Automation**

In case one of your projects is a Jira Service Desk project on Jira Cloud, then you could use Jira Service Desk Automations which is a free feature. It allows to define rules and actions to be performed. You can find more information [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confeval/jira-service-desk-evaluator-resources/jira-service-desk-automation).

**Automation Plugins**

There are a few other plugins (or 'apps') available on the Atlassian marketplace to automate certain tasks in your projects. They work similar to the Jira Service Desk Automation but are much more powerful and can be used in more than only Jira Service Desk (of course they support regular Jira projects). Your use case should be possible with them as well. Popular apps are [Automation for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1215460/automation-for-jira) (there is a lite/free version available) or [ScriptRunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/6820/scriptrunner-for-jira) (here you have to write your own scripts).

**Issue Synchronization Plugins**

There are also specialized plugins in case you want to continuously make sure that the issues in your two projects have the same data and the issue updates are synchronized to the other side as soon someone updates an issue. They not only provide you with settings for workflow updates but also regular issue field updates. Popular ones are [Exalate Jira Issue Sync](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1213645/exalate-jira-issue-sync-more) or [Backbone Issue Sync](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1215199/backbone-issue-sync-for-jira), but none of them is free to use. (Note: I'm currently working for the team behind Backbone Issue Sync).

Answer (score 0):

Although neither of the unswers suggest **free plugins** as requested, I also had some helpful comments in Atlassian Community:

[Sync fields](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1214812/sync-fields?hosting=server&tab=overview) is a plugin which is used to change and replicate all the data that is in a issue to another issue in other project ,may be this is similar plugin.

There are many options out there to do linked transitions:

[Jira Misc Workflow Extensions](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/292/jira-misc-workflow-extensions-jmwe?hosting=server&tab=overview) has a [transition linked issues post function](https://innovalog.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/JMWE/pages/68878506/Transition+linked+issues)

[JSU Automation Suite](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/5048/jsu-automation-suite-for-jira-workflows?hosting=server&tab=overview) for [Jira Workflows](https://confluence-apps.beecom.ch/display/JSU/Linked+Transition) also [has one](https://confluence-apps.beecom.ch/display/JSU/Linked+Transition)

You can also (partial list)

- Automation for Jira, (this one was recently purchased by Atlassian)
  one of the scripting addons (scriptrunner, power scripts)
- Jira Workflow Toolbox

So there are many options. Take a look at each of the addons and see which one has the most features that you would use in addition to linked transitions. They are all good choices, and all have their pros and cons.

Comment: I've updated my answer to better reflect which suggestions are 'free' ;-) But yeah, your list is also quite comprehensive, depending on what you want to achieve in the end ;-)

Comment: Successfully implemented interproject autotranstitions yesterday. The choice was JMWE's Transition Linked Issues. Also used autocreation of an issue in another project from the same plugin's post-functions.